# Can I override a method of a class template if it doesn't use the template parameter inside?

Tags: c++, overriding, eclipse-cdt, c++98, template-inheritance

I have the following code:

```
template <typename T>
class A {
public:
    virtual void func() {
        // Things that don't use T parameter.
    }
};

class B : public A<int> {
public:
    void func() {
        A<int>::func();
        // Working...
    }
};
```

Basically, I want to override a virtual function defined in a class template from inside a class that inherits from a specialized version of such template (A).

Does this work in C++? Is it good practice? Also, is it ok to call the overridden method as I did in the overriding one? (please, note that, for compatibility with the toolchain I'm using, this is C++98)

Thank you.

Comment: Yes you can. Do you have any specific problems with that?

Comment: `A<int>::func();` can be shortened to `A::func();`, otherwise looks ok.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Well, it compiles, but the IDE doesn't see it as an override (it doesn't add the override symbols near the declarations of the overriding methods) and I don't understand why. Usually it signals overrides when I make them. But being Eclipse CDT I couldn't understand if its a limit of the tool or something done wrong by me.

Comment: @fb9 Could well be an IDE only problem, it's perfectly OK to do so.

Comment: Most IDEs are somewhat dumb.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Thanks. I'm quite a newbie when it comes to templates.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Thanks for clarifying. Unfortunately I must use Eclipse for this job due to management decisions... I guess I will get used to this kind of things.

Comment: @fb9 Sometimes Eclipse CDT has problems with the _"intellisense"_, yes. I've been working with it several years, and got used to it. In the end if the compiler says it's OK, you can just ignore these glitches most of the time.

Comment: its not quite clear why you think it matters whether `func` uses `T` or not. In `A<int>::func` the template paramter  `T` is `int`, so you are bascially worrying about `func` using `int` or not. Your code is fine also when `func` does use `T`

Comment: @idclev463035818 Well, I wrote it to give more context to my question, I didn't know if it was important or not. As I said, I'm not quite familiar with templates. That's why I ask on SO, it helps me in connecting the dots by asking to someone more experienced than me. Thank you for your comment.